# Слайдер в слайдере на css + js

Tags: javascript, css

Как сделать слайдер в слайдере без использования Muse?

Пример на [Muse](http://istore.of.by/) (смотреть там, где возле телефонов есть кружок замены цвета и под телефоном замена цены).

Когда-то видел подобный наработки на `js` + `CSS`.

Проще говоря, необходимо, чтобы при выборе цвета должна отображаться цена на телефона в комплектации 16, 32, 64 гб. Допустим: мы выбираем серый. На этом фото показывается три кнопки (16, 32, 64), нажав на которые открывается цена. Мотаем на следующий цвет, допустим это белый. Опять 3 кнопки (цены везде разные).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начнём с того, что в указанном Вами примере это совсем никакой не слайдер.

Для того чтобы добиться подобного эффекта необходимо в любом используемом Вами слайдере, в блоке элемента отобразить примерно следующий код:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 // Вешаем слушателя на событие клик по элементу управления
 $('.controlItem').bind('click', function(){
   // Внутри берём его значение data-color и сохраняем в переменную
   var colorItem = $(this).data('color');
   // Удаляем у всех элементов класс visible чтобы их скрыть
   $('.phone').removeClass('visible');
   // Выбираем нужный элемент с таким же как у контроллера data-color и добавляем ему видимость
   $('.phone[data-color="' + colorItem + '"]').addClass('visible');
 });
});
```

```css
.pink {
  background: pink;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
.blue {
  background: blue;
}


.sliderItem .phone {
  display: none;
}
.sliderItem .phone.visible{
  display: block;
}

.phonesControllers .controlItem {
  float: left;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 20px 5px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #1f1f1f;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sliderItem">
  <!-- Устанавливаем для первого элемента класс visible для отображения. В каждом элементе определяем атрибут data-color для связи между элементом управления и отображаемыми элементами -->
  <div class="phone pink visible" data-color="pink">
    123
    <!-- Изображение телефона, какое-то спецефическое описание -->
  </div>
  <div class="phone red" data-color="red">
    234
    <!-- Изображение телефона, какое-то спецефическое описание -->
  </div>
  <div class="phone blue" data-color="blue">
    456
    <!-- Изображение телефона, какое-то спецефическое описание -->
  </div>
  
  <div class="phonesControllers">
   <!-- Отображаемые контроллеры. Так же определяем data-color для связи -->
   <div class="controlItem pink" data-color="pink">              
   </div>
    <div class="controlItem red" data-color="red">              
   </div>
    <div class="controlItem blue" data-color="blue">              
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Существуют и более лаконичные и изящные решения данной проблемы, но этот должен Вам подойти

Comment: В сущности, вы привели мне код обычного слайдера. А та проблема над которой я задумался сводится к тому, что внутри каждого слайда есть еще один набор переключателей, которые выводят, как показано в примере цены. Потому я и писал в задаче слайдер в слайдере.

Comment: А что, собственно, мешает внутри элемента слайдера реализовать тоже самое? Таким образом можно хоть слайдер в слайдере в слайдере в слайдере реализовать.

Comment: окей. Попробую в ближайшее время